# Validator.TryValidateObject Not Validating RangeAttribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

Given the following object,

```
public class Question
{
    [Required]
    public string QuestionText { get; set; }

    [Range(1, 5)]
    public int Difficulty { get; set; }        
}
```

With the following Validation Code

```
ICollection<ValidationResult> results = new List<ValidationResult>();
Question question = new Question();
ValidationContext ctx = new ValidationContext(question, null, null);
Validator.TryValidateObject(question, ctx, results);
// results.Length = 1
```

Why does Range attribute not create a validation error when Required does (the value is 0 obviously)?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Ah so it would seem I need to specify validateAllProperties = true

```
Validator.TryValidateObject(question, ctx, results, true);
```

Incidentally what was throwing me off was the fact I had an abstract base class with another property in it and without validateAllProperties the Validator will stop on the first error of ALL superclasses too.  So you will get a validation error for each superclass (in my case 2)

Comment: The original post is nearly 3 years old, I'd expect some drift in behaviour.

Comment: Turned out my problem was slightly different - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21111905/validator-tryvalidateobject-does-not-validate-attribute

Comment: Still works for me 6 years later - behaviour hasn't drifted that much, and still a surprise to me that the default is `false`.

Comment: Goodness. I can't believe `true` isn't the default for this. What a headache. Thank you

Comment: I feel this is as appropriate of an API choice as having a method called ShouldExecuteCode. Thanks, I missed this.

Comment: For those who are using dotnet 6 and still getting issue:
https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/64736

Answer (score 23):

`Validator.TryValidatorObject(instance, validationContext, validationResults)` calls `Validator.TryValidateObject(instance, validationContext, validationResults, validateAllProperties)` with `validateAllProperties = false`.

When validateAllProperties is `false`, only the `RequiredAttribute` will be validated.

Comment: My goodness what a mess is this. Hope Microsoft understand there is something called as the word "user friendly".

Comment: That is not intuitive at all. :(