# Dataannotations validation

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

on asp.net mvc3 I'm using dataanotations for validation. I control the validations on my controller with a simple if(ModelState.IsValid). How can I control those validations in a simple class, not a controller?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the validator helper class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validator.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty much what the MVC validator does behind the scenes:

This will iterate through all the annotations and figure our if there are any errors and add them to an error collection. It's best to put this in a base class then have all your other classes inherit from it. if `GetErrors().Any()` returns true, the model is invalid.

```
 public IEnumerable<ErrorInfo> GetErrors() {
            return from prop in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this).Cast<PropertyDescriptor>()
                   from attribute in prop.Attributes.OfType<ValidationAttribute>()
                   where !attribute.IsValid(prop.GetValue(this))
                   select new ErrorInfo(prop.Name, attribute.FormatErrorMessage(string.Empty));
        }
```

Error Info Class:

```
public class ErrorInfo{
public string Name { get; set; }
public string FormatErrorMessage { get; set; }    

public ErrorInfo(string name, string formatErrorMessage){
    Name = name;
    FormatErrorMessage = formatErrorMessage;

 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Answered Here (w/ .net 4): 
[Using ASP.Net MVC Data Annotation outside of MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3089760/using-asp-net-mvc-data-annotation-outside-of-mvc)