# Parameterising resource strings in Required attribute in Data Annotations

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-annotations

I hope the subject made sense :)

I'm not fussed about local/global stuff but if I have a resource named IsRequired with a value of "{0} is required." how to use with Data Annotations? (not MVC btw)

This will "work", of course:

```
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "IsRequired", 
ErrorMessageResourceType=typeof(Resources))]
```

But I'd need something like:

```
[Required(string.Format(ErrorMessageResourceName = IsRequired, "MyProperty"), 
ErrorMessageResourceType=typeof(Resources))]
```

(yes I know that won't work ;)

Is it possible to format the resource string in a data annotation required attribute? Why write 200 required resource strings when 1 will suffice?

Thanks,
Richard

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3089760/using-asp-net-mvc-data-annotation-outside-of-mvc

Comment: I'm already using Enterprise Library 5 VAAB.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to subclass `RequiredAttribute`:

```
public class MandatoryAttribute : RequiredAttribute
{
    // ...
}
```

You can then override the `Validate` method, in which you can inspect the `ValidationContext` for the property name and use that to produce the correct error message.